# Add calculated column to df2 for every row entry in df2 pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5],'Y':[1,2,3,4,5],'Point':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

| X | Y | Point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'Y':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |

I need to add a new column into df2 for every row entry in df1 and populate with the following equation

```
=sqrt((abs(df1.X-df2.X)**2)+(abs(df1.Y-df2.Y)**2))
```

Each new column title should correspond to the Point column entry in df1
whats the best way to do this

should look like this

| X | Y | Point1 | Point2 | Point3 | Point4 | Point5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1.41 | 2.83 | 4.24 | 5.66 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.41 | 0 | 1.41 | 2.83 | 4.24 |
| 3 | 3 | 2.83 | 1.41 | 0 | 1.41 | 2.83 |
| 4 | 4 | 4.24 | 2.83 | 1.41 | 0 | 1.41 |
| 5 | 5 | 5.66 | 4.24 | 2.83 | 1.41 | 0 |
| 6 | 6 | 7.07 | 5.66 | 4.24 | 2.83 | 1.41 |
| 7 | 7 | 8.49 | 7.07 | 5.66 | 4.24 | 2.83 |
| 8 | 8 | 9.90 | 8.49 | 7.07 | 5.66 | 4.24 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `cdist` function from `scipy`.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
output = pd.DataFrame(data=cdist(df1[["X", "Y"]], df2, 'euclidean'), 
                      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2[["X","Y"]]),
                      columns=[f"Point{i+1}" for i in range(5)]).reset_index()

>>> output
   X  Y    Point1    Point2    Point3    Point4    Point5
0  1  1  0.000000  1.414214  2.828427  4.242641  5.656854
1  2  2  1.414214  0.000000  1.414214  2.828427  4.242641
2  3  3  2.828427  1.414214  0.000000  1.414214  2.828427
3  4  4  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214  0.000000  1.414214
4  5  5  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214  0.000000
5  6  6  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214
6  7  7  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427
7  8  8  9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641
```

Comment: thanks, minor change, for cdist i needed to put [["X","Y"]] after df2 for it to work. I also changed the range from 5 to len(df1.index) so it works for a dataframe of any length